# Set Putty Window Title Dynamically to Hostname

Tags: networking, ssh, cisco, putty, juniper

Is any way to dynamically change the window title within Putty when jumping between devices?

The majority of my work is on Cisco/Juniper devices and in order to reach these devices, I use a Linux jump box. I effectively end up with a dozen open windows with no way of knowing which is which.

What would be ideal is if the Putty session would check the hostname of the device, ie Anything before the "#" and load it into the title of the window.

Putty may not do it, but if anyone knows of any terminal software that does (Kitty, SuperPutty) I would happily change as this is my biggest annoyance when many windows are open!

Thank You

Comment: See [Change Window Title of Putty Terminal Session](https://superuser.com/a/1334329) and the linked post to [Set PuTTY's window title to name of loaded session?](https://serverfault.com/questions/178469/set-puttys-window-title-to-name-of-loaded-session/745968)

Answer (score 2):

You can use TTY plus which allows you to have multiple tabs within one window which makes navigation easier. In original Putty you can set the window title in the settings tab under Window -> Behaviour. And if you use login@hostname instead of ip address to connect then it will be displayed in the title by default.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I have my kitty setup to dynamically change the title based on the host I'm logged on to.

[My kitty ssh client title config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oH11M.png)

Comment: These variables do not exist in plain PuTTY though.

Comment: True, was one reason why I decided to move to Kitty .